# Best-practice of saving multi-dimensional NSArray into NSUserDefaults

Tags: objective-c, nsarray, nsuserdefaults

In Obj-C I'm trying to save an array into `NSUserDefaults` I get an error. I guess it's because the array is multi-dimensional, but how is the best way to solve this? Should I encode/decode the entire object to string, or should I tweak my object in a way?

Below is the warning message. I have replace some of the match objects with "...", in order for the post not to be 100 miles long.

Thanks in advance!

```
*** -[NSUserDefaults setObject:forKey:]: Attempt to insert non-property value '(
        {
        items =         (
                        {
                awayName = Celtic;
                awayScore = 0;
                channel = TV3Sport1;
                dateEnd = 1377018000;
                dateStart = 1377010500;
                description = "Playoff til Champions League, 1. kamp.";
                hash = 05ec41bd5cb91fe559349391c007994d;
                homeName = "Shakhter Karagandy";
                homeScore = 0;
                leagueTitle = "Champions League (kval)";
                matchProgress = "";
                matchStart = 1377010800;
                stream = "";
            },
                        {
                awayName = "Real Sociedad";
                awayScore = 0;
                channel = TV3Sport1;
                dateEnd = 1377031500;
                dateStart = 1377023400;
                description = "Playoff til Champions League, 1. kamp.";
                hash = be7a7e4763038c6991ba9f6cddfce871;
                homeName = Lyon;
                homeScore = 0;
                leagueTitle = "Champions League (kval)";
                matchProgress = "";
                matchStart = 1377024300;
                stream = "";
            }
        );
        unix = 1376949600;
    },
        {
        items =         (
                        {...);
        unix = 1377036000;
    },
        {
        items =         (...);
        unix = 1377122400;
    },
        {
        items =         (...);
        unix = 1377208800;
    },
        {
        items =         (...);
        unix = 1377295200;
    },
        {
        items =         (...);
        unix = 1377381600;
    },
        {
        items =         (...);
        unix = 1377468000;
    },
        {
        items =         (...);
        unix = 1377554400;
    }
)' of class '__NSCFArray'.  Note that dictionaries and arrays in property lists must also contain only property values.
```

Comment: Looks like an array of dictionaries (or custom classes) to me. What is the structure you are trying to save. Are there any custom classes involved (that doesn't implement encoding/decoding)?

Comment: I've been trying to do this recently and didn't get anywhere.  The only option is to come up with some sort of name-flattening technique.  However it looks to me like you should be using sqlite or core data...

Comment: All this data came from a JSON request, which I then NSJSONSerialized and saved a valueFromKey inside of that.

Thanks to @Valentin Shamardin's post, I thought that I could just save the NSData from the JSON response instead of a part of the response. Now it works.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is not that the array is multi-dimensional (or the nesting necessarily). The issue is that the full structure can only contain instances of `NSData`, `NSString`, `NSNumber`, `NSDate`, `NSArray`, or `NSDictionary` - and somewhere you have an instance of some other class. You need to remove that class or convert it into one of the permitted types.

You might also want to consider whether storing such a large amount of data into user defaults is really what you want to do...

Answer (score 1):

Your model looks a little heavy and complicated. So I suggest you to learn about data persistence in iOS. There are few different options for saving your data between app launches:

- `NSUserDefaults`
- `NSCoding`
- Core Data
- storing in plist

Each strategy has own advantages and I can't give you a silver bullet. It depends on your model.